# Post and redirect to cross domain URL

Tags: python, redirect, post, http-post, flask-login

I want to post some data (say id=123) to a cross domain URL and then redirect to that URL. Code:

```
@app.route("/postreq", methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_webservice():
return redirect('127.0.0.1:3005/developer?id=123')
```

This redirect works fine but I want to send `id` via post request to hide it from query string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, redirecting GET to POST should be avoided, as the two verbs have different meanings: GET requests should be idempotent, POST request are supposed to modify the internal state of the application.

Secondly, after a POST, browsers usually can be redirected to a resource that they will fetch with GET (303 redirect code), or using the same POST verb (307 redirect code), but the spec (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) does not show a way to do GET -> POST.